# Spring unit testing - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, junit

hi i'm new with unit testing and when u tried to test my spring application, i can't resolve this probleme  Failed to load application context. Can not find the path [which I specified in @ContextConfiguration]
 here my code : 
-Application context :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.RealEstate")
@Import(ApplicationContext.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/images/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/Resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/Resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(internalResourceViewResolver);
    }

}
```

and here's my test class :

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebConfig.class})
public class CustomerDaoImplTest {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDao customerDao;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        // MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(customerDao);
    }

    @Test
    public void findById(){
        //Assert.assertNotNull(adminDao.readAdminById(1));
        //Assert.assertNull(adminDao.readAdminById(3));
        Assert.assertNull(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveCustomer(){
        //customerDao.storeCustomer(getSampleCustomer());
        //Assert.assertEquals(customerDao.getCustomersList().size(), 7);
        Assert.assertEquals(5+2, 7);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteCustomer(){
        customerDao.deleteCustomer("customer1");
        Assert.assertEquals(customerDao.getCustomersList().size(), 5);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteEmployeeByInvalidSsn(){
        customerDao.deleteCustomer("23423");
        Assert.assertEquals(customerDao.getCustomersList().size(), 6);
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllEmployees(){
        Assert.assertEquals(customerDao.getCustomersList().size(), 6);
    }

    @Test
    public void findEmployeeByUsername(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(customerDao.readCustomerByUsername("overflow"));
        Assert.assertNull(customerDao.readCustomerByUsername("paul"));
    }

    public Customer getSampleCustomer(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(7);
        customer.setName("ihab");
        customer.setLastName("benamer");
        customer.setEmail("benamer@gmail.com");
        customer.setUsername("ihab");
        try{
            customer.setBirthday(new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1996-11-10").getTime()));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e){
            ;
        }
        customer.setIdNumber("987521");
        customer.setAddress("consantine, algérie");
        customer.setPassword("123");
        customer.setPhone("+213557665392");
        customer.setSex("male");
        return customer;
    }

}
```

I have a structure like this:
java
  |com.RealEstate
     |config
     |dao
     |model
     |service
     |controller
test
  |com.RealEstate
     |config
     |dao

```
here's the error slack 
    saveAdmin(com.RealEstate.dao.AdminDaoImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.registerMvcSingletons(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:346)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.initWebAppContext(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.AbstractMockMvcBuilder.build(AbstractMockMvcBuilder.java:127)
    at com.RealEstate.dao.AdminDaoImplTest.setUp(AdminDaoImplTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: UPDATE : i tried to use xml context file instead of config class and i still getting the same error

Comment: Post the exception stack

Comment: @Dovmo i update the post

Comment: I would take out `@Import(ApplicationContext.class)`. That's unneccessary and might be screwing up your tests; not sure if that's the root reason however

Comment: i already tried to create all the beans in the WebContext class instead of 2 classed ( + ApplicationContext class) but i still had the same error